# Node.js + body-parser. HTTP Post Request from HTML form - Getting empty body

Tags: html, node.js, forms, http, body-parser

I'm trying to send data to a JavaScript server from an HTML form.

I tested the POST Request with Postman tool and on the server-side everything is working fine.

The issue is that from the HTML form I get an empty body.

This is the HTML form

```
<form name="newsletter" enctype="application/json" action="/add-to-newsletter" method="post" >
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="6u 12u$(medium)">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u$ 12u$(small)">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" value="INVIA" class="special" /></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>
    </div>
    <p style="margin-top:2.1em; font-size:1em;">Riceverai solo cose utili e divertenti</p>
</form>
```

This is the Javascript server

```
var express = require('express');
var db = require('./db.js');
var middleware = require('./middleware.js')(db);
var _ = require('underscore');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//POST /addNewsletter
app.post('/add-to-newsletter', function (req, res) {
    /*debug*/ console.log("This is the body you are trying to post in add-to-newsletter");
    /*debug*/ console.log(req.body);
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email');
    body.email = body.email.trim();
    body.newsletter = true;
    db.newsletterUser.create(body).then(function (user) {
        //mailing.sendLoginEmail(user.toJSON().email); /*deactivate not to send login mail*/
        res.json(user.toPublicJSON());
    }).catch(function (e) {
        /*DEBUG*/ console.log("Error in addNewsletter");
        /*DEBUG*/ console.log(e);
        res.status(400).json(e);
    });
});

// VARIOUS
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//LISTEN - REMOVE {force: true} NOT TO ERASE DB
db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
    app.listen(PORT, function (){
        console.log('Express listening on port ' + PORT);
    });
});
```

I've been trying different things like changing enctype to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and using external forms from tutorials but I always got the same result.

Comment: Possible values for enctype are: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, and `text/plain`. You probably want to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` from what i see in your form.

Comment: Also, we would need to see your server code to fully answer the question, since `enctype="application/json"` actually POSTs the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I edited with server code and tried with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but got the same result

Comment: try Adding id attribute to you form controls ie <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" />

Comment: Have you tried to use `bodyParser.urlencoded()` middleware and send form as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: That worked!

I resolved using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

If you write it as an answer, it will be accepted.

Thanks a lot